# Input box + select list + links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is this list not working?

I need to combine three things: input box + select list + links.

This is my attempt:

```
<input type="text" name="example" list="lemmas">
<datalist onChange="window.location.href=this.value" id="lemmas">
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/37CVfR9Z">A</option>
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/1kJWwbnz">a day</option>
</datalist>
```

Please help me to get a combo of this three things. After using the input box to select an option of the list and pressing ENTER the list has to open the link.

Thanks.

The following select works. I only need to add an input box to it:

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/37CVfR9Z">A</option>
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/1kJWwbnz">a day</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did it work? Always accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work accurately. Check the jsFiddle. I added an `id="autocomplete"` to the input field, jQuery checks when ENTER key is pressed in the field and based on that it redirects the page.

**Revised answer with ENTER key press event:**

```js
$(function(){      
      // check for key press event
      $('#autocomplete').keypress(function (e) {
          var key = e.which;
          var url = $(this).val();           
          // the enter key code
          if(key == 13) {
            if (url) { window.location = url; }
          }
          return false;
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="example" list="lemmas">
<datalist id="lemmas">
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/37CVfR9Z">A</option>
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/1kJWwbnz">a day</option>
</datalist>
```

Alternately you could also use on input change (without ENTER key press):

```
      $('#autocomplete').on('input', function(e) {
          var url = $(this).val(); 
          if (url) { window.location = url; }
          return false;
      });
```

Comment: What do you mean? Just use the revised version provided in jsfiddle. What's the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time reading about `<datalist/>` tag. It doesn't seem to have good browser support.

Anyways... you can attach an `oninput` event handler to your `<input/>` field. I don't like using event attributes, so I am attaching the event in the JavaScript.

```js
example.oninput = function () {
   window.location.href = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="example" id="example" list="lemmas">
<datalist id="lemmas">
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/37CVfR9Z">A</option>
   <option value="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/1kJWwbnz">a day</option>
</datalist>
```

Side-remark - you should probably add logic to verify that the value is a URL though...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to implement your code. I don't know about js and only need to add an input box to the form. Thanks.

Comment: Read [JavaScript Where To](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp).